# Transform FragmentActivity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I looking for transform a FragmentActivity Map example to Fragment for my app, i have already edit all things about context or import. I just have to put my new code in my old but i don't find where... (i know i'm ridiculous ^^)

This is my old Fragment code, is work very well in my phone:

```
package com.example.discover;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

public class Maps_fragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 20000; /* 20 sec */

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private boolean isPermission;

    public Maps_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);  //use SuppoprtMapFragment for using in fragment instead of activity  MapFragment = activity   SupportMapFragment = fragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                mMap.clear(); //clear old markers

                CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(37.4219999,-122.0862462))
                        .zoom(10)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(45)
                        .build();

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 10000, null);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.4629101,-122.2449094))
                        .title("Iron Man")
                        .snippet("His Talent : Plenty of money"));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.3092293,-122.1136845))
                        .title("Captain America"));
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I would like add this:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (latLng != null) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in Current Location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        startLocationUpdates();

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLocation == null) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {

            // mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
            //mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
//        mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
//        mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // You can now create a LatLng Object for use with maps
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        //it was pre written
//TODO        assert getFragmentManager() != null;
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
//TODO        assert mapFragment != null;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if (!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert();
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private boolean requestSinglePermission() {

        Dexter.withActivity(getActivity())
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        //Single Permission is granted
                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Single permission is granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        isPermission = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        // check for permanent denial of permission
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            isPermission = false;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();

        return isPermission;

    }
}
```

This fragment of app is a map where i can follow my position.
Thank's for all !

PS: this line don't work yet :)

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
implements  OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

This code was missing on class declaration.